Buenas tardes soy nuevo en esto como puedo mostrar mis registros despues de enviar mi formulario
con este guardo los datos en la base de datos:
    <script>$(document).ready(function () {
    
      // Listen to submit event on the <form> itself!
      $('#my').submit(function (e) {
        // Prevent form submission which refreshes page
        e.preventDefault();
    
        // Serialize data
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
          event.target.reset();
          $("#field").focus();
    
        // Make AJAX request
        $.post("enviar.cfm", formData).complete(function() {
      console.log("Success",);
    
        });
      });
    });
    </script>

Me pudieran ayudar como obtenerlos después de ser guardados

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y en que lenguaje? y que hay en el back? y que problema tuviste al hacer un back que devolviera los datos?

segun tu ejemplo no estas procesando el manejo de los datos

        $.post("enviar.cfm", formData).complete(function() {
      console.log("Success",);
    
        });


según la documentación de jquery no esta definido el método complete.
$.post("enviar.cfm", formData, (data) => {
    //aca tienes la respuesta de la enviar.cfm
    //enviando tu formData
    console.log(data)
})

existe esta aproximación aun mas detallada
$.post( "test.php", { func: "getNameAndTime" }, function( data ) {
  console.log( data.name ); // John
  console.log( data.time ); // 2pm
}, "json");

Espero te sirva saludos ✌
